# How to achieve something like anti-aliasing on 8x8 pixel font using TextMeshPro

Tags: unity, c#, text, fonts, text-mesh-pro

I use `TextMeshPro` for my UI text. My text is currently very crispy and looks like this

[image]

I'd prefer if it looked more like text in 90s arcade games, with more "anti-aliased" edges. For example,

[image]

I tried regenerating the TextMeshPro asset using different sampling point size, padding, and render modes (for example, Smooth vs Raster). I also tried using a few different shaders on the asset's atlas material (for example, Bitmap, Distance Field, and Distance Field SSD)

No matter what settings on the TexhMeshPro asset or which built-in shader I use on the asset's atlas material, I can't seem to achieve this effect.

**Any advice on how to achieve the more "anti-aliased" effect on the 8x8 pizel font?**

Comment: Hinting can produces different results on fonts, try experimeting with it, I am not familiar with unity however so I don't know where that would be located, but honestly any filtering will approach your original image to the one you wanted. You can try to use shader code or texture-based font to add filtering.